# How to change CSS for outer element?

Tags: html, css, focus

I have a page HTML5 with two element inputs, for email and password. I want to do the following:

1.- When I focused the input email, I want add CSS style to tag element **b**.
2.- When I focused the input password, I want add CSS style to tag element **b**.

is possible?

Thanks

This is my code:

CSS:

```
input.dx-texteditor-input:focus + .tooltip
{
  opacity: 1;
}              
input.dx-texteditor-input: focus + .tooltip-top-right
{
  right: 0; 
  left: auto; 
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label class="input">
    <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock" style="z-index: 1"></i>
    <div class="dx-texteditor dx-texteditor-empty dx-show-clear-button dx-widget dx-textbox">
        <div class="dx-texteditor-container">
            <input class="dx-texteditor-input" name="email" type="email">
            <div class="dx-placeholder"></div>
            <div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
                <span class="dx-clear-button-area" onclick="void(0)">
                    <span class="dx-icon dx-icon-clear"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right" style="opacity:0">
        <i class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i> Please enter email address/username
    </b>
</label> 



<label class="input">
    <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock" style="z-index: 1"></i>
    <div class="dx-texteditor dx-texteditor-empty dx-show-clear-button dx-widget dx-textbox">
        <div class="dx-texteditor-container">
            <input class="dx-texteditor-input" name="email" type="email">
            <div class="dx-placeholder"></div>
            <div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
                <span class="dx-clear-button-area" onclick="void(0)">
                    <span class="dx-icon dx-icon-clear"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right" style="opacity:0">
        <i class="fa fa-lock txt-color-teal"></i> Enter password
    </b>
</label>
```

Comment: Sorry, and edit my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Jquery selectors like this.

```
$(".form input").focus(function() {
  $(".form b").css("color","red");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5zbsbrp7/

Or use only css

```
input:focus + b {
    color: red
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/041jsrew/

Comment: Thanks but jQuery it's not allowed and my layout is different.